# How to inflate a view behind another

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Forgive me if this is a simple question however I am new to Android Development and this problem has been bugging me.

I have a "base" layout file which contains a RelativeLayout and a com.devspark.sidenavigation.SideNavigationView from [this library](https://github.com/johnkil/SideNavigation).

I then have an activity with a ViewPager which inflates other layouts (containing ListViews and progressBars) into this.  My issue is that however I try and do it, the SideNavigationMenu always appears behind the inflated listviews.  I'm not sure what's going wrong and I'm getting lost in a mess of Layouts.  Does anyone have any pointers?

Here is my "base" layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NewNews"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">  

<com.devspark.sidenavigation.SideNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/side_navigation_view_news"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and an example of one of the "sub"-layouts which are inflated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<eu.erikw.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_all"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar_all"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative layout doesn't support layers.

Views are placed on top of each other by the order they are added to the layout.

e.g.

- add viewA to relativelayout
- add viewB to relativelayout
- viewB will be infront of viewA

One way to inflate "behind" is inflating the other view before the other one is inflated.

- add viewB to relativelayout
- add viewA to relativelayout
- viewA will be infront of viewB

or remove the view and re-add it to the relativelayout

- add viewA to relativelayout
- add viewB to relativelayout
- remove viewA
- re-add viewA
- viewA will be infront of viewB

Comment: That did it.  I was getting confused as I was doing my adding inside onCreateView().  The return statement of this adds a view to the layout and so making that return the sidemenu and doing the adding/removing before worked.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this:

```
parentView.addView(childView, 0);
```

> Second parameter is index, the position at which to add the child

here second parameter is passed at 0 which makes the child view to be added in the back of views already present.